How to get rid of "PineconeApiException: (400)" and "ValueError: Index 'None' not found in your Pinecone project" in jupyter notebook?
I am using this link to learn langhain and pinecone. Just copy pasted the code as bellow:
I am using default PINECONE_API_KEY and using bellow code I am able to create index in pinecone, facing problem while saving embedding in index itself.
My Code:
import getpass
import os
import time

from pinecone import Pinecone

os.environ['HF_TOKEN'] = os.getenv('HF_TOKEN')
pinecone_api_key = os.environ.get("PINECONE_API_KEY")

pc = Pinecone(api_key=pinecone_api_key)


index_name = "langchain-pinecone-learning"  # change if desired

existing_indexes = [index_info["name"] for index_info in pc.list_indexes()]

if index_name not in existing_indexes:
    pc.create_index(
        name=index_name,
        dimension=3072,
        metric="cosine",
        spec=ServerlessSpec(cloud="aws", region="us-east-1"),
    )
    while not pc.describe_index(index_name).status["ready"]:
        time.sleep(1)

index = pc.Index(index_name)
index


embeddings=(
    OllamaEmbeddings(model="gemma:2b")  ##by default it ues llama2
)

Document is exactly similar to Document in article itself
from langchain_pinecone import PineconeVectorStore
vector_store = PineconeVectorStore(index=index, embedding=embeddings)
vector_store

Not there are 2 methods to save data in vector_db:
1.vector_store.from_documents(documents,embeddings)
2.vector_store.add_documents(documents=documents, ids=uuids)
In both cases I am getting different error:
For vector_store.from_documents(documents,embeddings):
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[28], line 73
     68 uuids = [str(uuid4()) for _ in range(len(documents))]
     70 # vector_store.add_documents(documents=documents, ids=uuids)
---> 73 vector_store.from_documents(documents,embeddings)

File u:\GENERATIVE_AI\genv\lib\site-packages\langchain_core\vectorstores\base.py:833, in VectorStore.from_documents(cls, documents, embedding, **kwargs)
    831 texts = [d.page_content for d in documents]
    832 metadatas = [d.metadata for d in documents]
--> 833 return cls.from_texts(texts, embedding, metadatas=metadatas, **kwargs)

File u:\GENERATIVE_AI\genv\lib\site-packages\langchain_pinecone\vectorstores.py:453, in PineconeVectorStore.from_texts(cls, texts, embedding, metadatas, ids, batch_size, text_key, namespace, index_name, upsert_kwargs, pool_threads, embeddings_chunk_size, async_req, id_prefix, **kwargs)
    407 @classmethod
    408 def from_texts(
    409     cls,
   (...)
    424     **kwargs: Any,
    425 ) -> PineconeVectorStore:
    426     """Construct Pinecone wrapper from raw documents.
    427 
    428     This is a user friendly interface that:
   (...)
    451             )
    452     """
...
    403         f"Did you mean one of the following indexes: {', '.join(index_names)}"
    404     )
    405 return index

ValueError: Index 'None' not found in your Pinecone project. Did you mean one of the following indexes: langchain-pinecone-learning
Output is truncated. View as a scrollable element or open in a text editor. Adjust cell output settings...

For second Case i.e vector_store.add_documents(documents=documents, ids=uuids):
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
PineconeApiException                      Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[18], line 70
     55 documents = [
     56     document_1,
     57     document_2,
   (...)
     65     document_10,
     66 ]
     68 uuids = [str(uuid4()) for _ in range(len(documents))]
---> 70 vector_store.add_documents(documents=documents, ids=uuids)
     73 # vector_store.from_documents(documents,embeddings)

File u:\GENERATIVE_AI\genv\lib\site-packages\langchain_core\vectorstores\base.py:282, in VectorStore.add_documents(self, documents, **kwargs)
    280     texts = [doc.page_content for doc in documents]
    281     metadatas = [doc.metadata for doc in documents]
--> 282     return self.add_texts(texts, metadatas, **kwargs)
    283 raise NotImplementedError(
    284     f"`add_documents` and `add_texts` has not been implemented "
    285     f"for {self.__class__.__name__} "
    286 )

File u:\GENERATIVE_AI\genv\lib\site-packages\langchain_pinecone\vectorstores.py:175, in PineconeVectorStore.add_texts(self, texts, metadatas, ids, namespace, batch_size, embedding_chunk_size, async_req, id_prefix, **kwargs)
    164 if async_req:
    165     # Runs the pinecone upsert asynchronously.
...
PineconeApiException: (400)
Reason: Bad Request
HTTP response headers: HTTPHeaderDict({'Date': 'Thu, 22 Aug 2024 08:58:57 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Content-Length': '104', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'x-pinecone-request-latency-ms': '1019', 'x-pinecone-request-id': '7419458757206642138', 'x-envoy-upstream-service-time': '41', 'server': 'envoy'})
HTTP response body: {"code":3,"message":"Vector dimension 2048 does not match the dimension of the index 3072","details":[]}
Output is truncated. View as a scrollable element or open in a text editor. Adjust cell output settings...


In pinecone V2:
from langchain_pinecone import PineconeVectorStore

vector_store = PineconeVectorStore(index=index, embedding=embeddings)

But we need to pass index_name as well:
from langchain_pinecone import PineconeVectorStore
vector_store = PineconeVectorStore(index=index, embedding=embeddings,index_name=index_name)
vector_store

also i case of from_documents() we have to pass index_name.
db = vector_store.from_documents(documents,embeddings,index_name=index_name)

And last while creating index pass dimension=2048.
Worked for me, but dont have any idea why copied code from document itself not worked earlier.
